# Diferença location.href ou location.assign

Tags: javascript

Qual a diferença entre `location.href = url` e o `location.assign(url)`? É algo no consumo de memória JavaScript? Existe alguma recomendação oficial de qual usar?

Eu considero o *location.assign* mais elegante e legível, mas cogito que ele consuma mais memória.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há diferença – exceto que `href` é uma propriedade, e assim também permite a leitura de seu valor, enquanto o método `assign` só permite a definição desse valor (e por consequência o carregamento de uma nova página).

Performance geralmente não precisa ser uma preocupação a menos que você esteja de fato vendo algum gargalo na aplicação. Neste caso específico, o uso de memória é irrelevante, já que após a troca do URL a página será recarregada e a memória utilizada pelo JS será zerada.

Comment: Pelo o que li, o `assign` pode emitir a exceção `SecurityError` em algumas situações e o `href` não se preocupa com isso. Não consegui entender direito em quais situações isso aconteceria. Sabe algo sobre isso?

Comment: Eu li que ele pode emitir essa exceção, mas não achei referência de que usar `location.href` como setter não faria o mesmo. Tem um link dizendo que o href não se preocupa com isso?

Comment: Eu li que o href é um pouco, bem pouco, mais rápido. Mas continuo achando muito estranho no meio do codigo você da um = e ele alterar a sua pagina, uma função fazer isso é algo muito mais logico para mim.

Comment: Acredito que eu tenha entendido errado na primeira leitura do item [5.5.3.1 Security](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-location-assign), que seria uma exceção ao `SecurityError`. Agora nem sei se entendi o que eu li kkk

Comment: Eu li isso também (no SO em inglês), mas se a diferença não é gritante pode estar na margem de erro do teste. Faz sentido o seu raciocínio, se você acha mais claro pode usar o `assign` sem problemas. @LuizSantos

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Acho que se trata da implementação do controle de CORS. Eu sigo acreditando que ambos acabam chamando [o mesmo algoritmo](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate).

Comment: @LuizSantos o `location.href` é uma variável. Se vc altera a variável, teoricamente altera o que ela deve mostrar.

Comment: Pois, por hora concordo contigo. A tarde irei ler com mais calma e verificar todas essas nomenclaturas de contextos envolvidas. No momento ficou confuso para mim.

Comment: Eu acabei por usar o href. So comentei que acho mais legivel o outro. A pergunta foi também para saber se algum pode ser descontinuado ou algo assim. Muito Obrigado a todos! :)

Answer (score 4):

Quando você usa o location.assign ele carrega aquele conteúdo da url, mas quando você usa o location.href ele funciona como um link tradicional, por isso é acho melhor fazer ancora com o href:

```
location.href = "#top";
```

E para carregar uma nova pagina location.assign:

```
location.assign("https://www.pagina.com");
```

Update -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**URLUtils.href**
É uma DOMString que contém toda URL.

**Location.assign()**
Carrega o recurso na URL fornecida como parâmetro.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Na verdade acho que nenhum dos dois funciona para âncoras.

Comment: Funciona esta no w3 https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Comment: Realmente, devia ter algo errado no teste que fiz. O assign também funciona

Comment: E não recarrega a página se eu passar uma âncora

Comment: Vale lembrar que W3Schools e W3C são coisas distintas. Por mais que a ideia do W3Schools seja apresentar de forma mais didática o W3C, o mais seguro é utilizar a própria página da W3C como referência. Ou até a página da WHATWG. [Sobre o W3Schools no meta...](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/692/5878)

Comment: Não sabia desta separação do w3 e do w3c.

Comment: Para facilitar, busque sempre a referência na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/) - ela por si só já é bem mais confiável que a W3Schools; mas, principalmente, sempre no final da página há uma tabela com os links para as especificações [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org) e [W3C](https://www.w3.org). Você pode utilizar a MDN para uma visão mais didática do contexto e as especificações para detalhes mais técnicos.

Comment: Fiz um nova edição levando em consideração os comentários.

Comment: Mas parece que você ainda está dizendo que eles se comportam diferente. Ou não?

Comment: Mas ao meu ver são diferentes, "É uma DOMString que contém toda URL", o que eu entendi com isso foi, ele tem somente a url, e como é usado no "location" ele chama a pagina, "Carrega o recurso na URL fornecida como parâmetro." agora se usar o assign ele de fato vai pegar o conteúdo da url e jogar na tela.

Comment: Tanto que se você fazer isso alert(location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com"), vai mostrar a url, mas se você fazer isso: alert(location.assign("https://www.w3schools.com")), vai retornar indefino.

Comment: `location.href = "w3schools.com"` retorna o próprio href e a chamada do método retorna undefined. Eu continuo achando quer setar com location.href ou assign dá exatamente o mesmo resultado...